# Aumentar tamanho bolinhas de campo para senha

Tags: html, css, input

eu to querendo aumentar o tamanho das "bolinhas" de um input password, pensei em por `input { font-size:140% /*exemplo*/ }` por exemplo. Contudo, somente a barrinha que fica piscando na hora da digitação que aumenta. 
As bolinhas de caracteres da senha não aumentam.
Quem puder ajudar, agradeço!

Comment: Mas elas já são BEM diferentes de browser para browser. Vai ficar meio complicado isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com CSS você basicamente pode mudar fonte e tamanho:

```
<input style="font-size:18px;width:85px;font-family:Lucida Console" type="password">
```

mas é imprevisível o que vai acontecer de browser para browser. O que dá pra fazer é você usar uma custom font, porém, nada garante que o browser vá realmente usá-la na prática.

A alternativa seria usar um JavaScript para trocar os caracteres de um campo texto, porém, há várias questões de segurança envolvidas.

Veja alguns testes no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/mw1n1nuh/)**, lembrando que depois que você conseguir deixar exatamente do jeito que quiser, vai testar em outro navegador e... Bam! Surpresa, tudo diferente!

Comment: pô, a falta que tá fazendo o stackfiddle por aqui, tá demorando :/

Answer (score 2):

Bom, fiquei curioso e o melhor que achei foi isso,

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){ /* START WEBKIT */
 INPUT[type="password"]{
 font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
 height:30px;
 font-size:30px;
 width:220px;
 padding:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
 }
}
```

Se você for alterando o font-size os bullets vão mudar de tamanho como você precisa porém tem que ir ajustando o height/width do input junto para que os bullets fiquem na posição certa.